# .htaccess nice url settings not redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been reading documentation and tutorials on .htaccess file setup all evening but nothing seems to pan out...

Based on some tools I found online, I'm looking to have the web-browser show non .html names in the navbar - ie. domain.com/contact/ instead of domain.com/contact.html

current .htaccess file contents are as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force search engines to use slowandlowcoastal.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^slowandlowcoastal\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://slowandlowcoastal.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^rates$ /rates.html [L]
RewriteRule ^trips$ /trips.html [L]
RewriteRule ^photos$ /photos.html [L]
RewriteRule ^videos$ /videos.html [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.html [L]
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Try removing L from: [R=301,L]

Comment: am i not correct to understand that "RewriteEngine On" is in fact enabling mod_rewrite? tried removing the L and it 404'ed my page.